# Multiple row select in HTML without the use of checkbox

Tags: html

I want to select multiple rows in a table without using a checkbox. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just visually select you're after, it's very possible with Javascript and CSS.

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com), or some other [JS library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries), you can add a HTML class to the row on click. Then use CSS to style that class.

jQuery:

```
$('tr').click(function(){ $(this).toggleClass('selected'); });
```

CSS:

```
tr.selected { background: #ccc; }
```

Comment: Of course, there's no reason why you couldn't back this with a hidden field that effectively emulated a checkbox from the form processor's perspective. That said, graceful degradation would be an issue. :-)

Comment: @middapark: "why you couldn't"* presumably :)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Yup. Fixified. Ta for the heads up. :-)

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't bother hiding the checkbox. This solution should really be an extension of the checkbox, for 508 compliance at least.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is related, but take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303294/how-to-find-selected-elements-with-jquery-ui-selectable) SO question.

It's using jQuery UI Selectable to perform a drag selection.  You can the [demo here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/) and [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#display-grid) for grid like setting.