# How to show value of LI by jquery selectable->select event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this `html`, representing list of words:

```
    <ul id="words">
        <li>word1</li> 
    </ul>
```

There is `jquery-ui` script I try to use to show selected value (in my case is "word1")

```
   $("#words").selectable({
        selected : function(event, item) {
            alert(item)
        }
    });
```

How make this script show me **"word1"** in alert-window?

Now it shows me '`[Object object]`'

---

I've been [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303294/how-to-find-selected-elements-with-jquery-ui-selectable). But it seems not nice solution, and rest just don't work.

Comment: `console.log` should show something more interesting than `alert`. I suspect it's handing you the DOM element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#words").selectable({
    selected: function (event, item) {
        alert(item.selected.innerHTML);
    }
});
```

Comment: ok. yes. this works. or even better then:  alert($(item.selected).text())

Answer (score 1):

You get the li element. You'll want its innerHTML so :

```
item.innerHTML
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $("#words").selectable({
    selected : function(event, item) {
        alert( $(item.selected).html())
    }
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qhXvN/4/

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-selected) says that the second parameter is an object (type: element) which means that it represents the DOM node (li). To get the contents of that DOM node you can use the jQuery selector $, and wrap the node, then use the .html() function in jquery to return the contents.

```
   $("#words").selectable({
    selected : function(event, item) {
        var val = $(item).html();
        alert(val);
    }
  });
```